How to integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{(1+t^5)\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{\left(\,{1 + t^{5}}\,\right)
\,\sqrt{\,{1 + t^{2}}}\,}{\rm d}t
$$
I have no idea how to integrate this function. This is from my Maths textbook.
Actually, the original question was as follows:

Find the area of the loop of the curve-
$$
x^{5} + y^{5} = 5a\,\left(\,{xy}\,\right)^{2}
$$

So, of course, it might be simpler to analyse this in polar coordinates.
Substitute $x = r\cos\left(\,{\theta}\,\right)$ and $y=r \sin\left(\,{\theta}\,\right)$.
The curve in terms of polar coordinates is:
$$
r = \frac{5a\cos^{2}\left(\,{\theta}\,\right)\sin^{2}\left(\,{\theta}\,\right)}
{\cos^{5}\left(\,{\theta}\,\right) + \sin^{5}\left(\,{\theta}\,\right)}
$$
Limits can be found by
$\sin^{2}\left(\,{2\theta}\,\right) = 0$.
Therefore, we have to integrate this from $0$ to $\pi/2$.
Dividing by $\cos^{6}\left(\,{\theta}\,\right)$ and substituting $\tan \theta = t$, we will get the integrand:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}
\frac{t^{2}}{\left(\,{1 + t^{5}}\,\right)\,\sqrt{\,{1+t^{2}}\,}\,}
{\rm d}t
$$
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Did you mean $x^5+y^5=5a(xy)^2$?

did you try $t=\frac12\left(u-\frac1u\right)$, $u=1..\infty$?

@vanderWolf I'll try it out right now. Thanks.

@J.G. I am really sorry. I just rechecked the question. Yes, you are absolutely correct, the curve is $x^5 + y^5 = 5a(xy)^2$. Let me add this edit to the question too.

@DavidH I am sorry, but I typed the wrong curve at first. Please check the question again.

$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{t^2}{\left(1+t^5\right) \sqrt{1+t^2}} , dt=\frac{G_{7,7}^{7,7}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{10},\frac{7}{10},\frac{9}{10} \
0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{7}{10},\frac{4}{5} \
\end{array}
\right.\right)}{32 \sqrt{5} \pi ^{11/2}}$ with Mathematica.


We would like to calculate the area $A$ of the closed loop in the curve
$$x^{5}+y^{5}=5ax^{2}y^{2};~~~\small{a>0}.$$
Substituting $(x,y)=\left(r\cos{\left(\theta\right)},r\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\right)$ and solving for $r$ as a function of $\theta$, we find
$$r{\left(\theta\right)}=\frac{5a\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos^{5}{\left(\theta\right)}+\sin^{5}{\left(\theta\right)}}.$$
The area is then found to be
$$\begin{align}
A
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\left[r{\left(\theta\right)}\right]^{2}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\left[\frac{5a\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}{\cos^{5}{\left(\theta\right)}+\sin^{5}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right]^{2}\\
&=\frac{25a^{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\sec^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\left[\frac{\tan^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}{1+\tan^{5}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right]^{2}\\
&=\frac{25a^{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(\frac{x^{2}}{1+x^{5}}\right)^{2};~~~\small{\left[\tan{\left(\theta\right)}=x\right]}\\
&=\frac{5a^{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{5x^{4}}{\left(1+x^{5}\right)^{2}}\\
&=\frac{5a^{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\left(1+y\right)^{2}};~~~\small{\left[x^{5}=y\right]}\\
&=\frac{5a^{2}}{2}.\\
\end{align}$$


Nice work. Thanks.

We can use Green's Theorem, which states that for a continuously differentiable vector field $ \mathbf{F} = (M, N) $, where $ M $ and $ N $ are functions of $ x $ and $ y $, over a positively oriented, closed curve $ C $ with a region $ D $:
$$
\iint_{D} \left( \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \right) \, dA = \oint_{C} M \, dx + N \, dy.
$$
To calculate the area $ A $ of a region $ D $ enclosed by a curve $ C $, we can choose a specific vector field for which the area integral becomes simple. A common choice is:
$$
M(x, y) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad N(x, y) = x.
$$
This choice simplifies the integral:
$$
\iint_{D} \left( \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \right) \, dA = \iint_{D} \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} \right) \, dA = \iint_{D} 1 \, dA = A.
$$
With this choice, Green's Theorem reduces to:
$$
A = \oint_{C} x \, dy.
$$
Since we have the curve $ x^5 + y^5 = 5a(xy)^2 $, let us proceed using the formula:
$$
A = \oint_{C} x \, dy.
$$
To use this formula, we need a parameterization of the curve $ C $. Let us use the substitution $ y = tx $ as a parameterization:
$$
x^5 + (tx)^5 = 5a(tx)^2 \cdot x^2.
$$
Simplify this:
$$
x^5 (1 + t^5) = 5a t^2 x^4 \implies x = \frac{5a t^2}{1 + t^5}.
$$
Then:
$$
y = tx = \frac{5a t^3}{1 + t^5}.
$$
This parameterization covers the loop in the first quadrant.
For $ y = \frac{5a t^3}{1 + t^5} $:
$$
dy = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{5a t^3}{1 + t^5} \right) dt = 5a \cdot \frac{3t^2(1 + t^5) - 5t^7}{(1 + t^5)^2} \, dt.
$$
Simplifying this:
$$
dy = 5a \cdot \frac{3t^2 - 2t^7}{(1 + t^5)^2} \, dt.
$$
Substitute $ x $ and $ dy $ into the area formula:
$$
\begin{align*}
A & = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{5a t^2}{1 + t^5} \cdot \frac{5a (3t^2 - 2t^7)}{(1 + t^5)^2} \, dt \\
& = 25a^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2 (3t^2 - 2t^7)}{(1 + t^5)^3} \, dt \\
& = 25a^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3t^4 - 2t^9}{(1 + t^5)^3} \, dt.
\end{align*}
$$
This integral can be simplified using substitution $ u = 1 + t^5 $, which yields the following result:
$$
\boxed{A = \frac{5a^2}{2}}
$$

For the question in title
$$I=\int
\frac{t^{2}}{\left(\,{1 + t^{5}}\,\right)\,\sqrt{\,{1+t^{2}}\,}\,}\,dt$$
Let
$$\frac{t^{2}}{1 + t^{5}}=\frac{t^{2}}{(t+1)(t-r_1)(t-r_2)(t-r_3)(t-r_4)}$$ and use partial fraction decomposition to face
$$I=A_0 \int \frac{dt}{(t+1) \sqrt{t^2+1}}+\sum_{i=1}^4 A_i \int \frac{dt}{(t-r_i) \sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$J_0=\int \frac{dt}{(t+1) \sqrt{t^2+1}}=\sqrt{2} \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{t+1-\sqrt{t^2+1}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$$J_i=\int \frac{dt}{(t-r_i) \sqrt{t^2+1}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{-r_i^2-1}}\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{r_i-t+\sqrt{t^2+1}}{\sqrt{-r_i^2-1  }}\right)$$ For the corresponding definite integrals
$$K_0=\sqrt{2} \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$$
$$K_i=\frac{2}{\sqrt{-r_i^2-1}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-r_i^2-1}}{1-r_i}\right)$$
Now, using
$$r_{1,2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\pm i \sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$
$$r_{3,4}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\pm i \sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8}}$$ and the nasty $A_i$ (except $A0=\frac 15$), the result
